# JavaScript Change CSS property of div depending on day of the week

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm in the process of creating a website. I'm displaying the opening hours. And the client has asked for the current day of the week to be highlighted.E.G. every day is displayed in the color black box but today's date is in a red box.

```
var d = new Date();
var weekday = new Array(7);
weekday[0] =  "Sunday";
weekday[1] = "Monday";
weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
weekday[4] = "Thursday";
weekday[5] = "Friday";
weekday[6] = "Saturday";

var n = weekday[d.getDay()];

if (n = 'Thursday') {
    $('coloured-box').css({"color":"green"});
}
```

The above is what I have no idea if it's right wrong or nearly there.

Comment: Is there a list of the days of the week that appears in your HTML code that you would like to be styled and, if so, could you include the relevant HTML code?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with `n < 'Thursday'`, do you mean `d.getDay() < 4`, and ` $('coloured-box')` is also most likely wrong, because there are not html elements with the tag name `coloured-box`.

Comment: What do you try to achieve with `n < 'Thursday'` ? That's two strings - why would you use `<`?

Comment: @t.niese sure, OP probably doesn't mean that, but you can have whatever tag names you want

Comment: `getDay()` returns a number (0-6) corresponding to the days of the week. It doesn't return the string name of the day of the week.

Comment: @SvenTheSurfer not what ever tag name you want, but you are right `coloured-box` would be valid because it contains a `-`, but it is still a draft.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be to get the current day, then set the class on the given element by its index in its container, like this:

```js
$('.coloured-box span').eq(new Date().getDay()).addClass('today');
```

```css
.coloured-box span.today { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="coloured-box">
  <span>Sunday</span>
  <span>Monday</span>
  <span>Tuesday</span>
  <span>Wednesday</span>
  <span>Thursday</span>
  <span>Friday</span>
  <span>Saturday</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Rory, with some tweaks to get this working with my exact scenario it works perfectly! Thankyou so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have a logic error.

```
if (n = 'Thursday') {
    $('coloured-box').css({"color":"green"});
}
```

You need to do a comparison using ==

```
if (n == 'Thursday') {
    $('coloured-box').css({"color":"green"});
}
```