# Change a class by the day of the week

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to have images show up only on certain days of the week, so I can automate this process and not have to do this from home every night.

I referred to this post in initially setting this up: [JavaScript Change CSS property of div depending on day of the week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45354991/javascript-change-css-property-of-div-depending-on-day-of-the-week)

Right now I have all their styles set to display:none, and am attempting to use JS to apply a class to the appropriate day of the week which then overrides the inline CSS, setting the display to block. However, something isn't working.

This is on Squarespace, if that is relevant.

```js
  $('.gene img').eq(new Date().getDay()).addClass('displayed');
```

```css
.gene img.displayed[style] {display:block !important;}
```

```html
<a href="/genes-special/">

<div class="gene">
  
<img name="SUNDAY">
    
<img name="MONDAY" style="display:none; margin-top:7px;" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/588652c7a5790a5d29f14d94/t/5c4b6382c74c50461d189c28/1548444556260/1-28.png?format=1000w">
  
<img  name="TUESDAY" style="display:none; margin-top:7px;" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/588652c7a5790a5d29f14d94/t/5c4b642a0ebbe8fdff7443a5/1548444720987/1-29.png?format=1000w">
  
<img  name="WEDNESDAY" style="display:none; margin-top:7px;"
src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/588652c7a5790a5d29f14d94/t/5c4b63fa8a922d0881f198c0/1548444679119/1-30.png?format=1000w">
  
<img name="THURSDAY" style="display:none; margin-top:7px;" 
 src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/588652c7a5790a5d29f14d94/t/5c4b63f2c74c50461d18a1e4/1548444668557/?format=1000w">
  
 <img  name="FRIDAY" style="display:none; margin-top:7px;" 
 src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/588652c7a5790a5d29f14d94/t/5c4b63e940ec9a53af2de8b6/1548444655398/?format=1000w">
    
<img name="SATURDAY"> 
    
</div>   
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't mess with adding classes of CSS much when doing things like this.

I've used this jQuery solution before. Updated to include your "gene" class and "img" type.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".gene img").eq(new Date().getDay()).show();
    });
</script>
```

> edit to add additional method

Placeholder for Image (if showing one): This method doesn't pull the image until it is needed, instead of pulling all of them with html, and then just not showing the image if it is the wrong day.

```
<div class="gene">
    <img />

</div>
```

Then specify your images in the jquery ready function. There is a check if the day exists, and if it doesn't, just hides the entire .gene div.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var href = new Array(7);

        href[1] = "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/588652c7a5790a5d29f14d94/t/5c4b6382c74c50461d189c28/1548444556260/1-28.png?format=1000w";
        href[2] = "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/588652c7a5790a5d29f14d94/t/5c4b642a0ebbe8fdff7443a5/1548444720987/1-29.png?format=1000w";
        href[3] = "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/588652c7a5790a5d29f14d94/t/5c4b63fa8a922d0881f198c0/1548444679119/1-30.png?format=1000w";
        href[4] = "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/588652c7a5790a5d29f14d94/t/5c4b63f2c74c50461d18a1e4/1548444668557/?format=1000w";
        href[5] = "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/588652c7a5790a5d29f14d94/t/5c4b63e940ec9a53af2de8b6/1548444655398/?format=1000w";
        var day = new Date().getDay();
        if(day in href){
            $(".gene img").attr("src",href[day]);
        } else {
            $(".gene").hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I got this to work on my test page but not the one I actually want it on. I'm in a bit over my head. I should probably learn jquery and javascript.

Comment: What are the differences between the test page and the actual page? and which method did you use?

Comment: Got it!  Just put the jquery /javascript right in the code block instead of the code injection.  Thanks for this, it's going to save me a lot of trouble going forward

Comment: glad you got it working! please accept an answer, or submit your own if different than either of the two answers here, and then mark it the accepted answer to let others know the problem is solved and possibly help someone else in the future

Answer (score 0):

Here's a plain JS alternative. Thanks to [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7446819/dan-ringhiser) for the idea.

```js
(function() {

  var hrefs = new Array(7);

  hrefs[1] = "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/588652c7a5790a5d29f14d94/t/5c4b6382c74c50461d189c28/1548444556260/1-28.png?format=1000w";
  hrefs[2] = "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/588652c7a5790a5d29f14d94/t/5c4b642a0ebbe8fdff7443a5/1548444720987/1-29.png?format=1000w";
  hrefs[3] = "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/588652c7a5790a5d29f14d94/t/5c4b63fa8a922d0881f198c0/1548444679119/1-30.png?format=1000w";
  hrefs[4] = "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/588652c7a5790a5d29f14d94/t/5c4b63f2c74c50461d18a1e4/1548444668557/?format=1000w";
  hrefs[5] = "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/588652c7a5790a5d29f14d94/t/5c4b63e940ec9a53af2de8b6/1548444655398/?format=1000w";

  var dayNum = new Date().getDay();
  var image = document.createElement("img");

  if (dayNum in hrefs) {
    document.getElementById("gene").appendChild(image);
    image.src = hrefs[dayNum]
  }

})();
```

```html
<a href="/genes-special/">

  <div id="gene">
  
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: I just added that to the code block, but it's still not showing up.  Is it possible squarespace wouldn't support this particular code?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution without jQuery