# Change the color of a div based on the day of the week. Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a block and I want to change the color of the block based on the day of the week. I have no idea how to do this or how to go about doing it. Any suggestions? I have scanned stack overflow and there is nothing that changes the color of a div based on the day. The other answers highlight the day of the week and display all 7 days. This is not what I am looking for I am looking for the color of the box to change based on the day of the week. For example on Monday the block would be blue nothing else would be displayed except for a blue box. Tuesday it would be red nothing else would be displayed except for a red box. and so on for all 7 days.

As of now I have just created it and assigned it the color blue.

```html
<div class="box blue" align="center" style="width: 500px; height: 500px; background-color: blue;  margin: auto;"></div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45354991/javascript-change-css-property-of-div-depending-on-day-of-the-week

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript Change CSS property of div depending on day of the week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45354991/javascript-change-css-property-of-div-depending-on-day-of-the-week)

Comment: Do you want same color regardless of which day or different color for each day?

Comment: No it is not. I looked at it but it does not assign a different color to the div based on the day of the week.

Comment: Rob no i want to assign each day a different color. The color of the div will represent the day of the week. For example on monday it is blue on tuesday red... ect

Comment: @klajdiziaj930, In that answer they used an array for storing weekday names, you can use it for storing colors, with an array named `daycolor` of 7 colors, you can use `$('.box ').css({"color":daycolor[(new Date()).getDay()]});`